# how to get the list of arguments of a stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to get the list of arguments of a stored procedure in postgresql, is there any query to get the arguments ?

I got one system procedure to do the same, which is :

```
SELECT pg_get_function_identity_arguments('funcname'::regproc);
```

But here when there are more than one functions with same name then it will return an error.

Any solutions??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

It's too late for OP but anyway: I  searched answer today myself and did not found needed answer.

I came up with this solution:

```sql
SELECT 
        pronamespace::regnamespace,
        proname,
        pg_get_function_arguments(oid) AS args_def, -- full definition of arguments with defaults
        UNNEST(string_to_array(pg_get_function_identity_arguments(oid), ',' )) AS arg -- each argument with type
    FROM 
        pg_proc
```

Works in postgresql 11.x, I suppose that must work in other versions too but not tested.

Hope this helps somebody in future.

Answer (score 0):

For [my tool that reports PostgreSQL schema](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557-dump-postgresql-db-schema-to-text/) I use something like:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN pg_proc.proretset
        THEN 'setof ' || pg_catalog.format_type(pg_proc.prorettype, NULL)
        ELSE pg_catalog.format_type(pg_proc.prorettype, NULL) END,
    pg_proc.proargtypes,
    pg_proc.proargnames,
    pg_proc.prosrc,
    pg_proc.proallargtypes,
    pg_proc.proargmodes,
    pg_language.lanname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_language ON (pg_proc.prolang = pg_language.oid)
WHERE
    pg_proc.prorettype <> 'pg_catalog.cstring'::pg_catalog.regtype
    AND (pg_proc.proargtypes[0] IS NULL
        OR pg_proc.proargtypes[0] <> 'pg_catalog.cstring'::pg_catalog.regtype)
    AND NOT pg_proc.proisagg
    AND pg_proc.proname ilike 'MY_FUNCTION_NAME'
    AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'
    AND pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(pg_proc.oid);
```

See 2nd and 3rd column of its result.

Comment: Its giving values as : `proargtypes` as `<Other>` and `proargnames` as `<UnknownType (2,003)>`

Comment: What tool do you use to see results? In `psql` and `pgAdmin` for one of my function I see: "1043";"{nr0}". There `{nr0}` is the name of the only argument and `1043` is type. Then I do `select pg_catalog.format_type('1043', NULL)` to see that 1043 means `character varying`.

Comment: I'm using `SQuirrel SQL Client` to query the database.
In my fuction there are more more than one arguments passing, but in yours there is only one argument, so will that make out any difference ??

Comment: Can you use `psql` or `pgAdmin`? I tested it with function with more arguments and it returns '"23 1043 1043 1114 23 1043 1043 1043 23 1043";"{code,status_str,src,dbcurrenttimestamp,tmpuserid,remote_addr,sessionid,http_host,fu_index,script_name}"'. You can also try to run my tool to report database schema and see how your function is reported.

Comment: yup... its working with pgAdmin, thanks... But y its not working with Squirrel? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean version:

```
SELECT 
proname,
unnest(proargnames) as arguments, 
unnest(string_to_array((oidvectortypes(proargtypes)), ',')) as 
arguments_type
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p   ON    pronamespace = n.oid     
JOIN    pg_type t ON p.prorettype = t.oid  
WHERE   nspname = 'public'
group by proname, proargtypes, proargnames;
```